# Loading csv data to bigquery using python in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Read csv  file and load it to bigquery through dataflow job - use python coding for this instead of templates 
How perform this task using terraform(GCP) anyone help

I trying to do it but not understanding what terraform script should I write for it

Comment: Terraform deploy resources, it runs nothing. Don't mix the usages!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the responsability of `Terraform` to deploy a `Dataflow` job.

There is only a `Terraform` resource to instantiate a `Dataflow` [template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataflow_job)

You can deleguate this to your CI CD.

**Example with `Beam` `Python` :**

- Develop the Job with `Beam` `Python`
- Through your CI CD, deploy the `Python` `Beam` code to a `Cloud Storage` bucket
- Run the `Dataflow` job and main file with `Python` command line

**Example with `Beam` `Java` and `mvn` `compile` :**

- Develop the Job with `Beam` `Java` and Maven or Gradle
- Through your CI CD, run `mvn compile` command to execute the `Dataflow` job

**Example with `Beam` `Java` and a `fat` `jar` :**

- Develop the Job with `Beam` `Java` and Maven or Gradle
- Through your CI CD, generate a `fat` `jar`
- Deploy this `fat` `jar` to a `Cloud Storage` bucket
- Run the `Dataflow` job and the `Main` inside the fat jar with `java -jar` command

**Example with `Beam` `Python` and `Airflow`/`Cloud Composer` :**

- Develop the Job with `Beam` `Python`
- Through your CI CD, deploy the `Python` `Beam` code to the `Cloud Composer` bucket with `gcloud composer`
- In the `Airflow` code, uses `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` to instantiate the `Dataflow` job
- Run the `Airflow` `DAG` to run the `Dataflow` job

**Example with `Beam` `Java` and `Airflow`/`Cloud Composer` :**

- Develop the Job with `Beam` `Java`
- Through your CI CD, generate a `fat` `jar`
- Deploy this `fat` `jar` to a `Cloud Storage` bucket
- In the `Airflow` code, uses `BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator` to instantiate the `Dataflow` job targeting on the path of the `fat` `jar`
- Run the `Airflow` `DAG` to run the `Dataflow` job

Comment: Hi Mazlum Tosun I have try it but not understanding which terraform scripts use for it so if u have any script for it can u provide please

Comment: Ok I am going to share with you some sample scripts.

Comment: Hi Mazlum Tosun , Thanks for ur help please share scripts

Comment: Hi Mazlum Tosun , Thanks for ur help please share scripts